# hdiutil attach/detach/convert results to "resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-high-sierra

Since MacOS 10.13 I have the following problem.

1. `/usr/bin/hdiutil attach "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -mountroot /tmp`

```
/dev/disk3              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk3s1            Apple_APFS                      
/dev/disk4              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk4s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /private/tmp/MyDrive
```

2. `/usr/bin/hdiutil detach -force -debug "/tmp/MyDrive"` or `diskutil eject "/tmp/MyDrive"`

```
process_detach: entry with "/tmp/MyDrive"
util_verify_dev_entry: entry with "disk4s1".
process_detach_deventry: about to unmount_and_eject disk4s1
unmount_and_eject(disk4s1)
LetDIDriverSettleDown: calling IOServiceWaitQuiet...
DI_kextWaitQuiet: about to call IOServiceWaitQuiet...
DI_kextWaitQuiet: IOServiceWaitQuiet took 0.000005 seconds
LetDiskImageDriverSettleDown: wait took 0.000066 seconds
_unmountCallback: disk4
"disk4" unmounted.
"disk4" ejected.
```

3. `/usr/bin/hdiutil convert "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -format UDZO -o "target/MyDrive.dmg" -debug`

```
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
writeable: false
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
writeable: false
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for 
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for 
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, 
CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for 
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CCarbonBackingStore
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe: setting initial rval to +100
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for 
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, 
CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi Automator/Midi Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg).CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Users/aguelle/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for 
file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 6 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi%20Automator/Midi%20Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, 
CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setPermission: opening /Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi 
Automator/Midi Automator/target/MIDI Automator-tmp.dmg
CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: mapping flags 0x00000000 -> 0x00000014 (locks are MANDATORY)
CBSDBackingStore:OpenLockFriendly: could not open with lock 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 35
DIResolveURLToBackingStore: unable to resolve to any backing store class. 35. 
DIResolveURLToDiskImage: resolving backing store/file encoding failed. 35. 
convert: unable to recognize "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg":
resource temporarily unavailable.hdiutil: convert: result: 35`
```

1. `/usr/bin/hdiutil attach "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -mountroot /tmp`
2. Eject MyDrive via mouse click in Finder
3. `/usr/bin/hdiutil convert "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -format UDZO -o "target/MyDrive.dmg"`

-> Result: Conversion worked fine

So what is the difference between `hdiutil detach`, `diskutil eject` and ejecting from Finder?

Analysis:
`lsof [device]` gives no output as the device is not left after `hdiutil detach` at least `mount` shows none.

`diskutil info "disk4s1"` or `diskutil info /tmp/MyDrive`:

```
Device Identifier:        disk4s1
Device Node:              /dev/disk4s1
Whole:                    No
Part of Whole:            disk4
Volume Name:              MyDrive
Mounted:                  Yes
Mount Point:              /private/tmp/MyDrive
Partition Type:           41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
File System Personality:  APFS
Type (Bundle):            apfs
Name (User Visible):      APFS
Owners:                   Disabled
OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 Disk Image
SMART Status:             Not Supported
Volume UUID:              A3EE0B42-A021-47AA-B424-E494B75049D3
Disk / Partition UUID:    A3EE0B42-A021-47AA-B424-E494B75049D3
Disk Size:                212.5 MB (212471808 Bytes) (exactly 414984 512-Byte-Units)
Device Block Size:        4096 Bytes
Volume Total Space:       212.5 MB (212471808 Bytes) (exactly 414984 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Used Space:        184.7 MB (184709120 Bytes) (exactly 360760 512-Byte-Units) (86.9%)
Volume Available Space:   27.8 MB (27762688 Bytes) (exactly 54224 512-Byte-Units) (13.1%)
Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes
Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         No
Device Location:          External
Removable Media:          Removable
Media Removal:            Software-Activated
```

Answer (score 4):

`hdiutil` is really for working with disk images just as you are doing.  The eject in finder is essentially `diskutil eject [device]`.  `hdutil detach` is to "detach a disk image and terminate any associated process" (from the man page).  Where diskutil is for "manipulating the structure of of local disks" (from the man page).  Functionally, `hdiutil detach` is the same as `diskutil eject`. How it works though depends on if Disk Arbitration is running.

Disk Arbitration is framework and is in process diskarbitrationd that gets started by launchd and is always on by default.  It handles the mounting and unmounting of disks attached via USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt, ect.

According to the man page on hdutil, when Disk Arbitration is running. `hdutil detach` will use it to unmount any file systems and detach the image.  But if diskarbitrationd is not running then it will try and unmount filesystems and detach the image directly with a system call to ioctl.  I don't recall for certain if `diskutil -eject` uses the Disk Arbitration framework but I want to say that it does.

It might be interesting to try and figure out why you getting that error.  It typically means that exclusive access was not obtainable.  You might experiment with `lsof [device]` This will show all the ope files and PIDs and lot more for the device, and this can maybe give you clues as to what is giving the [EBUSY] error (Resource Temporarily Unavailable).  You can use `mount` with no argument to list all the devices and mount points if you don't know what device it is.  I believe that you can also do `lsof [mount/point]`.  The man page for lsof is your friend, and it is very long.

Another diagnostic is to use the -verbose option with hdiutil.  It is available with all verbs.  So, `/usr/bin/hdiutil -verbose convert "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -format UDZO -o "target/MyDrive.dmg"` might provide some enlightenment.

And yet another possible source of clues would to have have an additional Terminal.app window open with the command `diskutil activity` running when you try the steps that cause the error.  This command continuously reports on all Disk Arbitration framework activity.  Ctrl-C to stop the process.

You have a workaround that is working for you so maybe looking into why it is giving the error isn't important or interesting to you. Also, if you don't want to use Finder you can always use `diskutil eject [device]` from the terminal.  I have noticed a lot of things that are not quite right since I 'upgraded' to High Sierra and based on blogs around the net, it seems Apple is breaking things in the name of security and their new filesystem.  I doubt in this case it is security related but I wouldn't be surprised if they introduced a bug altering commands and frameworks to work with APFS.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately diskutil eject "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" behaves the same like hdiutil detach -> a conversion breaks with "resource temporarily unavailable". So there is still a difference between the terminal command and the Finder GUI command. I need this for a build script, so clicking in the finder is not an option for me.

Comment: @Angelo  Interesting problem.  Have you tried  `/usr/bin/hdiutil detach -force -debug "/tmp/MyDrive"` to see if there are any clues as to what is causing the busy signal?

Comment: @Angelo  Also, just out of curiosity, is `/usr/bin/hdiutil eject -force "/tmp/MyDrive"` behaving the same as detach?

Comment: @C Knight. Thanks for getting back. The `/usr/bin/hdiutil detach -force -debug "/tmp/MyDrive"` did not bring any new information to me. I added the output to the original post. `/usr/bin/hdiutil eject -force "/tmp/MyDrive"` does not help. I just encountered that I am not able to turn off the Disk Arbitration Framework. It just instantly restarts the process after I killed it.

Comment: @Angelo  How about replacing the -verbose option in step 3 with the -debug option?  Does it give any new information?  By the way, -debug will also activate -verbose on all recent versions of macOS.

Comment: @Angelo So this in an intriguing problem to me.  I have thus far been unable to replicate the error you are having.  I was looking again at your post to try and see if I am missing something and noticed that in step 2, when using the command line, the entry point for your image is disk4s1.  That is a little unexpected to me.  I would have expected it to just be disk4.  Are you working with a multi-partition disk image?  What is the output to the terminal when you run `/usr/bin/hdiutil attach "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -mountroot /tmp` ?

Comment: @Angelo After you have attached the image, what is the output of `diskutil info "disk4s1` and `diskutil info "/tmp/MyDrive"` ?   I am currently suspecting something with your image that the Finder's eject is resolving or ignoring and the command line methods are not.

Comment: @C Knight Ok I debugged the conversion (good idea btw.) but I am not sure if I can find any hint about the problem.

Comment: @ Angelo  It failed at the line that ends with (locks are MANDATORY).  The next line SHOULD have been something like `CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: setting F_SETBACKINGSTORE
(RO lock acquired)`.  You said that it will work when using Finder's eject.  Run step three again and pipe the output to a file then go through the steps with Finder Eject and also do the convert with debug enabled and pipe to a file then do a diff on the two files.  Not being able to get an exclusive lock means failure because the next steps after the lock is obtained is to set permissions and then some settings.

Comment: The character limit in comments is really annoying.  Anyway, it is still looking like something is holding your file open.  Could be a backup utility, antivirus,  or some other utility.  I think some lsof tracing maybe useful.  Do you have a muti-partition image?  I am still curious about the results of my last two questions yesterday.

Comment: @C Knight Many thanx again for your effort. We are comming a bit closer:
`/usr/bin/hdiutil detach -force -debug "/tmp/MyDrive"`
`sudo lsof | grep "MyDrive-tmp.dmg"`

Result:
diskimage 69316           xxxx    3u      REG                1,5  212510208 8595098668 /Users/xxxx/Documents/git/Midi Automator/Midi Automator/target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg

When I eject it manually, there is no file handle as expected.

Comment: Sorry @Angelo - I got really busy.   Yeah it sounds like we might tracking down what is causing the error, It is going to take me a bit to go through what all you've posted.

Comment: @Angelo  So I am not having any luck duplicating your error.  I am trying to figure out what all is different about what you are doing and what have done to try and mimic what you are doing.  One thing I see right off the bat that I cannot replicate is that you are using Apple

Comment: Apple's new APFS.  I have not worked with APFS yet but what I have read about it suggests that it is heavily depended on hard links.  I am not sure how convert functions with APFS and if there are limitations on converting HPFS images.  Have you tried your steps with another APFS image?  It maybe worth it to create another image and test it, and try doing so with both APFS and HFS+ type filesystems.  APFS is new and Apple is still working out bugs and adding support.  I can't help but wonder if you've stumbled into that since this process worked for you prior to High Sierra.

Comment: On further thought, it can't be hdiutil convert since it works when you use finder to eject.... Hmmm.  This is is quite the puzzle.  Also, it looks like you have multiple partitions in your image.  Can you elaborate on the image that you are working with without divulging anything personal/private/proprietary?  I want to try and replicate as much as I can the type and structure of the image you are working with except I don't have flash or fusion drives so I can't create HPFS images.  I am highly skeptical about the reliability of a filesystem that is dependent on hard links.

Comment: Puhhh.. I dont have any clue, but it seems to be a specific MacOS problem with ejecting the image via terminal.

Comment: Except that I can't duplicate it.  That is why I think it may have something to do with the image also.

Comment: So it is a problem with APFS. Creating the image with ´/usr/bin/hdiutil create -srcfolder "target/MyApp.app" -volname "MyApp" -ov "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -fs HFS+ -format UDRW´ works like a charme and solves my problem.

Comment: I am glad that you got it figured out.  I was wondering if APFS was the issue since you had said that it had worked prior to High Sierra.  I was just not able to test that on my end since I don't have any flasher fusion drives.

Answer (score 4):

I also observed the problem that on newer OS X versions after `hdiutil detach` the DMG was still occupied by `diskimage-helper` and I could not do `hdiutil convert` due to the error message you got.

My solution simply was to copy the source file first, because that works without problem and then do the convert on the copy. This works without problems for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

@Angelo Thank you for the insight:

> So it is a problem with APFS. Creating the image with ´/usr/bin/hdiutil create -srcfolder "target/MyApp.app" -volname "MyApp" -ov "target/MyDrive-tmp.dmg" -fs HFS+ -format UDRW´ works like a charm and solves my problem. –
> Angelo Berlin

In High Sierra (10.13.6), the additional argument, -fs HFS+ resolved my (and same) issue described here.

Details:

```
hdiutil create foo.dmg -srcfolder junk -format UDRW -size 1.1M -volname foobar
hdiutil attach foo.dmg -readwrite
hdiutil detach /Volumes/foobar
hdiutil convert foo.dmg -format UDZO -o fooConverted.dmg -imagekey zlib-level=9
hdiutil: convert failed - Resource temporarily unavailable
```

No joy. Same as everyone else.
But create and specify the filesystem with -fs...

```
hdiutil create foo.dmg -srcfolder junk -format UDRW -size 1.1M -volname foobar **-fs HFS+** -ov
hdiutil attach foo.dmg -readwrite
hdiutil detach /Volumes/foobar
hdiutil convert foo.dmg -format UDZO -o fooConverted.dmg -imagekey zlib-level=9 -ov
created: /Users/mjo/Documents/Code/bitcoin/bitcoin/fooConverted.dmg
```

This works like a champ! or as stated above, a charm.

Last, I tried the sequence of hdiutil commands without **-fs HFS+** on Big Sur. All's good. Clearly an (old) issue with High Sierra.